# How to copy a schema with another name but with same data?

Tags: oracle, oracle-9i

I want to copy all the objects of Scott schema to another schema.

I can not understand what the code should be. Like bellow one?

`create user scott1 identified by tiger1;`

Answer (score 3):

It's a quite old database. Your SQL command creates new user.

You can use Export in order to copy contents of one schema to another.

`exp FILE=$ORACLE_HOME/scott_export.dmp LOG= $ORACLE_HOME/scott_export.log OWNER=scott`

Create new user as you have shown in your post and grant required privileges.
Then import it to new schema.

`imp FILE=$ORACLE_HOME/ scott_export.dmp LOG= $ORACLE_HOME/scott_import.log FROMUSER=scott TOUSER=scott2`

Details are [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96652/ch01.htm) and [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96652/ch02.htm)